# Rails 4.2.7 mysql set two custom primary key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables called Post and Like. I want to set "ip" and "reference to post" as my two primary key in Like table. I can successfully create the likes table with two unique key 'ip' and 'id' from posts table. But when I try to create sample data from my rails console it will first check if the same 'ip' exist. If the same 'ip' is already existing it will not create the data even if the post is completely a different one.

This is what I have so far.

Likes Table

> ```
> class CreateLikes < ActiveRecord::Migration   def change
>  create_table :likes, :id => false do |t|
>    t.string :ip, limit: 39
>    t.references :post, index: true, foreign_key: true
>
>    t.timestamps null: false
>  end
>  add_index :likes, ["ip"], :unique => true   
>  add_index :posts, ["id"], :unique => true 
> end
> ```
>
> end

Posts Table

> ```
> class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration   def change
>  create_table :posts do |t|
>    t.string :title
>    t.string :body
>    t.string :media
>
>    t.timestamps null: false
>  end   
> end
> end
> ```

Comment: Kindly note that `t.references :post` adds a column of type integer named `post_id`, and not the named `post`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two primary key in a single table doesn't make sense. If you really have two keys that will always uniquely identify data, you can have a combined key of those two keys, and that combined key will act as a primary key.

Here's is how you can accomplish this in Rails:

```
class CreateLikes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  create_table :likes, id: false do |t|
    t.string :ip, limit: 39
    t.references :post, index: true, foreign_key: true

    t.timestamps null: false
  end
  execute "ALTER TABLE likes ADD PRIMARY KEY (ip,post_id);" 
end
```

And in your `Like` model:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_keys = :ip, :post_id
end
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the usage of combined key.